# Retraining Sentiment Analysis Annotator: Changing File to a Binarized Tree Issues

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to retrain the Sentiment Analysis Annotator. I am struggling with trying to change my file to a binarized tree with the following call:

`$ java -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.BuildBinarizedDataset -input sample.txt`

**Here are the errors I keep running into:**

```
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:7: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.io does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
                          ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:8: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.ling does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
                            ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:9: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.ling does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
                            ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:10: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.ling does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
                            ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:11: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
                                  ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:12: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
                                        ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:13: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeBinarizer;
                                        ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:14: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.process does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
                               ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:15: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.trees does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
                             ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:16: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.trees does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Trees;
                             ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:17: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.util does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Generics;
                            ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:18: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.util does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Pair;
                            ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:19: error: package edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging does not exist
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.Redwood;
                                    ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:28: error: package Redwood does not exist
  private static final Redwood.RedwoodChannels log = Redwood.channels(BuildBinarizedDataset.class);
                              ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void setUnknownLabels(Tree tree, Integer defaultLabel) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void setPredictedLabels(Tree tree) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void extractLabels(Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> spanToLabels, List<HasWord> tokens, String line) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Pair
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void extractLabels(Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> spanToLabels, List<HasWord> tokens, String line) {
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class HasWord
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
  public static boolean setSpanLabel(Tree tree, Pair<Integer, Integer> span, String value) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
  public static boolean setSpanLabel(Tree tree, Pair<Integer, Integer> span, String value) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class Pair
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
  private static final Redwood.RedwoodChannels log = Redwood.channels(BuildBinarizedDataset.class);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable Redwood
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    for (Tree child : tree.children()) {
         ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    for (Tree child : tree.children()) {
         ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    tree.label().setValue(Integer.toString(RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree)));
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable RNNCoreAnnotations
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
        spanToLabels.put(new Pair<>(i, i + pieces.length - 1), pieces[0]);
                             ^
  symbol:   class Pair
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!(tree.label() instanceof CoreLabel)) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class CoreLabel
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreLabel label = (CoreLabel) tree.label();
    ^
  symbol:   class CoreLabel
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
    CoreLabel label = (CoreLabel) tree.label();
                       ^
  symbol:   class CoreLabel
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:89: error: package CoreAnnotations does not exist
    if (label.get(CoreAnnotations.BeginIndexAnnotation.class).equals(span.first) &&
                                 ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:90: error: package CoreAnnotations does not exist
        label.get(CoreAnnotations.EndIndexAnnotation.class).equals(span.second)) {
                                 ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:94: error: package CoreAnnotations does not exist
    if (label.get(CoreAnnotations.BeginIndexAnnotation.class) > span.first &&
                                 ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:95: error: package CoreAnnotations does not exist
        label.get(CoreAnnotations.EndIndexAnnotation.class) < span.second) {
                                 ^
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    for (Tree child : tree.children()) {
         ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
    CollapseUnaryTransformer transformer = new CollapseUnaryTransformer();
    ^
  symbol:   class CollapseUnaryTransformer
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
    CollapseUnaryTransformer transformer = new CollapseUnaryTransformer();
                                               ^
  symbol:   class CollapseUnaryTransformer
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:167: error: cannot find symbol
    SentimentModel sentimentModel = null;
    ^
  symbol:   class SentimentModel
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
    LexicalizedParser parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parserModel);
    ^
  symbol:   class LexicalizedParser
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
    LexicalizedParser parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parserModel);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable LexicalizedParser
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:190: error: cannot find symbol
    TreeBinarizer binarizer = TreeBinarizer.simpleTreeBinarizer(parser.getTLPParams().headFinder(), parser.treebankLanguagePack());
    ^
  symbol:   class TreeBinarizer
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:190: error: cannot find symbol
    TreeBinarizer binarizer = TreeBinarizer.simpleTreeBinarizer(parser.getTLPParams().headFinder(), parser.treebankLanguagePack());
                              ^
  symbol:   variable TreeBinarizer
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:193: error: cannot find symbol
      sentimentModel = SentimentModel.loadSerialized(sentimentModelPath);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable SentimentModel
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:196: error: cannot find symbol
    String text = IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(inputPath);
                  ^
  symbol:   variable IOUtils
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
      DocumentPreprocessor document = new DocumentPreprocessor(sin);
      ^
  symbol:   class DocumentPreprocessor
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
      DocumentPreprocessor document = new DocumentPreprocessor(sin);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class DocumentPreprocessor
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:213: error: cannot find symbol
      List<HasWord> tokens = document.iterator().next();
           ^
  symbol:   class HasWord
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:219: error: cannot find symbol
      Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> spanToLabels = Generics.newHashMap();
          ^
  symbol:   class Pair
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:219: error: cannot find symbol
      Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> spanToLabels = Generics.newHashMap();
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Generics
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:226: error: cannot find symbol
      Tree tree = parser.apply(tokens);
      ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:227: error: cannot find symbol
      Tree binarized = binarizer.transformTree(tree);
      ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
      Tree collapsedUnary = transformer.transformTree(binarized);
      ^
  symbol:   class Tree
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:233: error: cannot find symbol
        Trees.convertToCoreLabels(collapsedUnary);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Trees
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
        SentimentCostAndGradient scorer = new SentimentCostAndGradient(sentimentModel, null);
        ^
  symbol:   class SentimentCostAndGradient
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
        SentimentCostAndGradient scorer = new SentimentCostAndGradient(sentimentModel, null);
                                              ^
  symbol:   class SentimentCostAndGradient
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
      Trees.convertToCoreLabels(collapsedUnary);
      ^
  symbol:   variable Trees
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
BuildBinarizedDataset.java:244: error: cannot find symbol
      for (Map.Entry<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> pairStringEntry : spanToLabels.entrySet()) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class Pair
  location: class BuildBinarizedDataset
55 errors
error: compilation failed
```

**Can someone help me figure out how to fix this please? I have already tried adding the CoreNLP repository to eclipse and adding the jar files, however, it's still not working. What do I do?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.